# Http Request Failed To Read Facebook users Photo - php sdk

Tags: php, facebook

I created An facebook photo app.It grabs users friends and it creates photos using gd library .
It is successfully creating photos some times ,but many time i get the below error.

Please say some alternate ways to correct error.
when i remove imagecreatefromjpeg from **https://graph.facebook.com/100001233159114/picture?hi.jpg ,imagecreatefromjpeg** throwing invalid jpeg image.

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(https://graph.facebook.com/10000123315911/picture?hi.jpg)
[function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403
Forbidden in /home/free/public_html/hi/34/main.php on line 133
```

Comment: I also get this error. 50% chance fail to open the stream. Looking for solutions

Answer (score 1):

Try putting "/" before "?"
like https://graph.facebook.com/100001233159114/picture/?hi.jpg

It should work

Answer (score 0):

That URL returns a HTTP redirect to the actual image location - does imagecreatefromjpeg() handle that?
Why not use the return value of `http://graph.facebook.com/<ID>?fields=picture` and pass that in instead?

Comment: how to get return value of a redirect?